# Exception thrown in prod environment: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-cli

My **angular CLI-generated** application runs fine in `dev` environment but when I switch to the `prod` environment by generating the app as such:

```
ng build -prod
```

I get the following exception:

```
Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property
```

I suspect that something has gone wrong with minification/mangling...

Can someone please help? My version of ng CLI is **1.0.0-beta.10**.

**edit 1**: Here is my `main.ts`:

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {provideRouter} from "@angular/router";
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {
  TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
  TranslateService,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateStaticLoader
} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";
import {AppComponent} from "./app/app.component";
import {SessionService} from "./app/session/session.service";
import {UserAccountService} from "./app/useraccount/useraccount.service";
import {ApplicationRequestOptions} from "./app/session/session.utils";
import {StylingService} from "./app/shared/services/styling.service";
import {AppRoutes} from "./app/routes/app.routes";
import {environment} from "./app/environment";
import {FormBuilder, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, provideForms, disableDeprecatedForms} from "@angular/forms";
import {PasswordValidationService} from "./app/shared/services/password-validation.service";
import {validatePassword} from "./app/shared/validators/password.validator";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provideRouter(AppRoutes),
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
  Title,
  FormBuilder,
  REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,
  SessionService,
  UserAccountService,
  StylingService,
  TranslateService,
  PasswordValidationService,
  disableDeprecatedForms(),
  provideForms(),
  {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: ApplicationRequestOptions},
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
  {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (http:Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'), deps: [Http]
  }
]);
```

and my `app.component.ts`:

```
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {TranslateService} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";
import {NavbarComponent} from "./shared/components/navbar.component";
import {FooterComponent} from "./shared/components/footer.component";
import {SigninComponent} from "./session/session.signin.component";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/components/home.component";
import {SessionService} from "./session/session.service";
import "moment/locale/fr";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
              <section class="container-fluid row Conteneur">
                 <navbar></navbar>
                 <section class="container">
                    <router-outlet (onActivate)="setTitle($event)"></router-outlet>
                 </section>
              </section>
              <section class="container-fluid">  
                <footer></footer>
              </section>
              `,
  directives: [NavbarComponent, FooterComponent, SigninComponent, HomeComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private translate:TranslateService,
              private sessionService:SessionService,
              private titleService:Title,
              private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    let userLang = 'fr';
    translate.use(userLang);
    moment.locale(userLang);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sessionService.reloadPersonalInfo();
  }

  setTitle($event) {
    this.translate.get(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data['titleKey'])
      .subscribe(translation=>this.titleService.setTitle(translation));
  }
}
```

Here is my home component template:

```
<div>
<a [routerLink]="['/signin']">signin</a>
</div>
```

and class:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class HomeComponent {
}
```

Comment: It might be an issue with the ng CLI build process. I have therefore opened an issue on the ng CLI github: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1446

Comment: I think there may be something else going on, because I am running on beta.10 and am using routerLink's without issue.   Have a github somewhere?

Comment: How do you build your app? With or without `-prod`?

Comment: both, i use `ng-serve` or `ng build` when developing and `ng build --prod` when building for prod.

Comment: Make sure you are using `[routerLink]`, have `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` pulled in as a directive on the component and that you have `provideRouter pulled in as part of the router config you are bootstrapping with the app.

Comment: I have edited my post and included the component that causes the exception.

Comment: Also, how would you explain it works in `dev` and not in `prod`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118328/discussion-between-zmanc-and-balteo).